# LINQ to entities query with count of parent depending on optional child collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

I have to found the count of Table1 such that

```
Table1
    Table2(optional)
        Table3(ICollection) where one column has matching value
    
    Table4 (optional)
        Table5
            Table6(ICollection) where one column has matching value
```

I tried something like

```cs
context.Table1.Where(
                 h.Table2 != null && h.Table2.Table3.All(m => m.xyz == ""
                   )
                   && h.Table4 != null && h.Table4.Table5.Table6.All(
                       j => j.sadsad == "asd"
                   )
                ).              
                Count();
```

But thinking usage of All or Any might be wrong approach

Comment: You need to provide a much clearer explanation of the problem. Perhaps include some sample data and expected results.

Comment: It should be `All` Table3 match? Or at least one?

Comment: Atleast one. I have used All just for reference

Comment: Got it @GertArnold

Comment: "might be wrong approach" isn't much better.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to check for null when building such EF Core queries.

```cs
context.Table1
    .Where(t1 => t1.Table2.Table3.Any(t3 => m.xyz == "") 
        && t1.Table4.Table5.Table6.Any(t6 => t6.sadsad == "asd")
    ).Count();
```

Comment: this Any or All approach is correct? i thought there is the need of join or so. I am mostly an sql guy or does basic LINQ till date

Comment: `Any` translates to EXISTS (... predicate), `All` translates to NOT EXISTS (... Inverted predicate). You do not need explicit JOINS, navigations replace them.